# Console Keyboard press detection lib or standard options?

Tags: c++, console, keyboard-events

i'm making a console game but i don't want the system to wait every time i tell it to detect a press (like cin)... Does anyone know how i can get a console window to detect keyboard presses, its ok if it's just letter key detection too, i can make do!

Comment: Maybe.  Which hardware and operating system?

Comment: A games loop polls the input devices for events.  That's not covered by the standard C++ library.  Certainly by whatever operating system you run on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Windows, the kbhit( ) function is the guy you want. If it's *nix, here's a [**kbhit( ) emulator**](http://www.pwilson.net/kbhit.html). kbhit( ) returns immediately (no blocking) with a flag that says that there is or is not a keyboard character waiting to be read. You can test the flag to see if you should issue a keyboard read.

Comment: Ok so how can i get the actual value of the key pressed?